# Why is Mathematica unable to solve an integral than can solved with WolframAlpha?

Tags: mathematica

The integral in question is this:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} [\cos^{-1}(\sin x)]^2~dx$$

The Mathematica code is

**Integrate[(Acos[Sin[x]])^2/2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]**

Attempting this with Mathematica appears to be fruitless. It won't even do a numerical integration. WolframAlpha, however, deftly provides

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} [\cos^{-1}(\sin x)]^2~dx=\frac{\pi^3}{3}\approx 10.335$$

However, WA also declares a step-by-step solution is unavailable.

Incidentally, I know that the WA solution is correct because I have verified it numerically.

Comment: The Mathematica function to use is ArcCos, not Acos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, because Mathematica is a programming language and has a defined syntax. The function is called `ArcCos` and not *Acos*:

```
Integrate[(ArcCos[Sin[x]])^2/2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}] 
(* Pi^3/3 *)
```

Comment: Thanks.I suspected that but it gave me the correct interpretation in writing out the integral with $\cos^{-1}$.